# Node Status "NotReady" After "terraform apply" command

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I created AWS EKS and Managed Node Group with Terraform. Actually it is working clearly. But, whenever i create namespace and run "terraform apply" command, my Nodes status becoming "NotReady". If i delete the node groups and run "terraform apply" command again, it is successfully running.
Anyone have idea about this problem??
Thanks.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "nodes_general" {
  name               = "eks-node-group-general"
  assume_role_policy = file("./policies/node-groups/node-group-policy.json")

}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "amazon_eks_cni_policy_general" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.nodes_general.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "amazon_eks_cluster_policy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy"
  role = aws_iam_role.nodes_general.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "amazon_eks_worker_node_policy_general" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.nodes_general.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "amazon_ec2_container_registry_read_only" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
  role       = aws_iam_role.nodes_general.name
}

resource "aws_eks_node_group" "nodes_general" {
  cluster_name    = var.cluster_name
  node_group_name = "nodes-general"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.nodes_general.arn
  subnet_ids = ["subnet_id_1", "subnet_id_2", "subnet_id_3"]
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 2
    max_size     = 5
    min_size     = 1
  }
  update_config {
    max_unavailable = 1
  }
  ami_type             = "AL2_x86_64"
  capacity_type        = "ON_DEMAND"
  disk_size            = 50 #100GB need to be
  force_update_version = false
  instance_types       = ["t3.small"]
  labels = {
    role = "nodes-general"
  }
  version = "1.20"
  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.amazon_eks_worker_node_policy_general,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.amazon_eks_cni_policy_general,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.amazon_eks_cluster_policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.amazon_ec2_container_registry_read_only
  ]
}
```

Comment: Without any code it's hard to assume anything.

Comment: Hi @MarkoE i uploaded the eks node group terraform code.

Comment: Ok, and you are using terraform to create the namespace as well?

Comment: yes, whenever i created "xxxx" namespace with terraform "namespace.yaml". The node status are being NotReady (but namespace has been created before that). I am deleting node group and running "terraform apply" again, namespaces are creating successfully and everything is working well

Comment: And these are the name space code;
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: argocd